# D3 : Retrieve data from SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is it possible to retrieve data from an svg via d3?

I have following scenario:
on page Resize I need to update the widths of an svg which was generated on a server via d3 . So for example the x-axis. However the client side d3 library has no knowledge of the svg. I noticed that with each DOM object there is a __ chart__ object. Is there some way i can access the range and domain for example and update them accordingly?

Comment: In principle yes, but this would be quite painful. Given that the SVG is generated using D3, why not do it all client side?

Comment: For performance reasons we required the svg's to be generated server side, and build a client library around it to handle events on the svgs. I'll probably have to expose some more information withe rgards to the svg

Answer (score 0):

When you create an SVG on the server and transfer it to the client, only the actual SVG DOM gets transferred, not any javascript objects or properties (such as the d3 `__data__` property) that you used in creating it.

So in order to attach data to the SVG elements that actually gets passed with the file, you would need to create an attribute of that element that contains the data.  Then you can select the element client side and parse the data attribute.

Example:

```
/*** Server Side ***/
/* if `bars` is a d3 selection of rectangles in a bar graph */
bars.attr("data-name", function(d){return d.name;})
    .attr("data-value", function(d) {return d.value;});

/*** Client Side ***/
var bars = d3.selectAll("rect.bar")
             .datum(function(){
                return {
                  name: this.getAttribute("data-name"),
                  value: this.getAttribute("data-value")
                }
             })
             .on("click", function(d,i){
                 /* do something with the data */
             });
```

That works if the data in question is simply a few numbers or names that you want to use in tooltips or similar interaction.  It doesn't work for a complex object like a chart function.  If you're need to redraw/resize the chart client-side, I really don't see any performance benefit in trying to draw the graphs server-side.

You can create server scripts to parse all your data into a ready-to-use format, maybe even run the d3 layout functions to create a ready-to-draw JSON array.  But then draw the graph client-side.